# HTTPS issue iOS9

Tags: php, ios, xcode, swift, https

yesterday I updated Xcode with iOS9 and new Swift and it did conversion , but after this I have a problem with HTTP connection, in this line code:

```
let jsonData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: self.url)!)!
```

I get this error:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

`self.url`'s values is : `http://localhost/testing/test.php?`

Reading on web I read that Apple forces to use HTTPS and I read also a way to disable this adding this lines to info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

but it doesn't work and I get the same error.

For now I don't want to use HTTPS because it's localhost , in the future yes but now no.

How do I resolve this problem?

P.S I use XAMPP for Mac

Comment: no one knows how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double check that you marked the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` value as a boolean. This is a screen shot that works:

[image]

Comment: yes , my screen is like yours but I get the same error , may depend on what?

Comment: And are you sure it's in the plist not in the project settings

Comment: sorry its the first time that I do this, How do I check this?